# Undeclare Variables in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to undeclare variables in C#? If so, how?

Comment: Can you please describe your scenario? Why do you think you need to undeclare a variable? Are you dealing with unmanaged resources? Are you creating many object and keep their references? Do you expiration any performance issues? Are you coming from C++?

Comment: Can you clearly define what the word "undeclare" means to you? because I have no idea whatsoever what "undeclare" means as a verb. I know what an "undeclared local variable" is -- a local variable that you intended to declare but neglected to do so. Undeclared local variables are an error in C# but allowed in some languages, like VBScript. I just can't figure out what you mean by the verb form. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't take care of undeclaring in C# (I think you mean unallocating by the way, don't you?) or any other .Net languages, the garbage collector takes care of unallocating the memory associated with the variable.

For unmanaged resources (fonts, database connections, files, etc), you need to call the Dispose method, either explicitely or by placing the variable in an using block.

More information about the .Net garbage collector: http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/garbage-collection/

Answer (score 12):

close the scope (introduced with '{') that contains the variable declaration:

```
int c=0;
{
 int a=1;
 {
  int b=2; 
  c=a+b;
 } // this "undeclares" b
 c=c+a;
} // this "undeclares" a
```

Comment: This is not the same as undeclaring. It's also not recommended practice except in odd circumstances. It creates arbitrary nesting when you could (and should) just be using a new variable name.

Comment: @Noldorin, +1 from me. Whilst it would provide the same effect *almost* as being able to undeclare a variable, it would make for a nightmare in code maintainability. The desire to undeclare a variable almost always indicates a need to refactor a method into multiple separate methods.

Comment: I love this solution. I had an issue with switch statement meant to sort logic for one specific object(s) and I really want to call the object by the same name in each case, while its possible for a single object when I need both the single object in some cases and `foreach` amount on others this allows me to use the same name for all. making it neat. I would love to know why in my case this would be bad practice. and it doesn't require any special "effort for maintainability" since is just using the blocks on a per case basis.

Answer (score 1):

You don't - when a variable goes out of scope or no more references exist to it, it automatically gets garbage collected.

Why would you want to explicitly do this anyway; what's the context? Most likely you should simply be using a new variable name, or refactoring the relevant section of code into a new function.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is **IDisposable**, you can use them within the `using` Block. In rest of the cases I'd go with what `Luther` has mentioned.

```
using (Car myCar = new Car())
{
    myCar.Run();
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer, in most cases when the object is IDisposable you **should** wrap it in a `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible in current languages. A plausible scenario is this:

```
void doSomething(String objectId) {
  BusinessObject obj = findBusinessObject(objectId);

  // from this point on the objectId should not be used anymore
  undef objectId;

  // continue using obj ...
}
```

Another scenario is when you implement some method from an interface, and you want to make sure that you don't use one of the parameters, especially in long methods.

```
Object get(int index, Object defaultValue) {
  undef index, defaultValue;

  return "constant default value";
}
```

This would also serve as a documentation that the programmer thought about these otherwise unused parameters.

Comment: `undef` is in Perl

Comment: @Yetti99 `undef` in Perl resets a variable to an undefined value, it doesn't remove the variable from the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing as undeclaring objects i .Net. If your object uses resources that needs to be cleaned up it should implement the IDisposable interface. Otherwise the garbage collector will take care of everything.